# LINQ Select Many - Modify flattened collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a class named ACTIVITY. This class contains a list of Laps, and each Lap has a collection of TRACPOINTS.

ACTIVITY --many--> LAPS ---many --> TRACPOINTS.

Whenever I fLatten the TRACPOINTS collection I get the list of all the TRACPOINTS. But when I modify those of course the originals don't get modified since it's a copy.

Is there any way that whatever change I made to the flattened tracpoints gets changed in the Tracpoints list for each lap?

Comment: Why? Is `Tracpoint` a `struct`?

Comment: could u put some code please

Comment: ... and until we see the definitions of these types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as TRACPOINT is a struct, it is not possible in any reasonable way.

Whenever you assign a value of struct variable or field to another variable or field, its contents are copied. The same holds for passing it as a method argument or returning it from a method, its value is copied. This is value semantics [1]. Compare this to atomic types like `int`, which have value semantics too. You would probably expect the following code to print 2, not 3.

```
static function Change(int j) { j = 3; }
static void Main(string[] args) { 
   int i = 2;
   Change(i);
   System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

If you do SelectMany, each value from the collection is probably assigned to some temporary local variable and then returned from the iterator (SelectMany), therefore it is copied and in fact possibly copied many times before it comes out from the iterator. So what you are updating is a copy of the struct. Like in the example, you're not changing variable `i`, but its copy stored in variable `j`.

This is why structs should be immutable. Instead of having properties with getters and setter in your struct, they should have only getters. For changing values of properties of a struct, you can implement methods that copy the whole original struct, change the value of the desired property and return the new struct instance. In fact, again, its copy will be returned. Example:

```
struct S {
   int f;
   public int F { get { return this.f; } }
   public S SetF(int newVal) {
      var s = new S();
      s.f = newVal;
      return s;
   }
}

var x = new S();
x = x.SetF(30);
```

That said, it could be possible to achieve what you want with pointers and unsafe C#, but believe me, it will be way easier to change your structs to classes, so that they have reference semantics instead of value semantics, or keep them structs, but make them immutable and do not use Linq, but old school loops. If you want to use Linq for something like SelectMany in such scenario, you probably do not care about performance difference between structs and classes so much...

[1] [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664472(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664472%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)